# What does "ad indicem" mean in a citation?

Tags: citations, language

I've seen this latin term in footnotes several times and still don't know the meaning of it. It is usually used like this:

[34] About this, see John Smith 2003, ad indicem.

or like this:

[65] Jane Smith 2006, 98-101, and ad indicem.

What does it mean? Does it mean "there are too many pages in this book related to this topic. I don't want to list them all. Just go check the index yourself"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be short, **yes**.

According to the [post in English.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/343646/define-ad-indicem-in-bibliography/343654#343654), it means *'see the index'*. It basically tells you to refer the index section and look for the topic that is discussed in the context where it is cited.

Note: This question was asked in both Academia.SE and English.SE to benefit both communities as there isn't a single standard dictionary that could be found online to define this term. Credits go to the [original answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/343646/define-ad-indicem-in-bibliography/343654#343654) in English.SE for answering my post.